# Button on Button HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

Is it possible to have a button that is on top of another button.. 
( **not above** )

I want to have a button on top of a button so that if a user unchecked a checbox then the top button disappears.

Comment: Why dont you just make it so that when they uncheck the checkbox the button changes to be a new button? Or at least a new function.

Comment: Maybe a more direct question is why do you want to do this?

Comment: If you are asking about to have a `button` tag inside another `button` tag, it is not valid HTML.

Comment: i have tried your suggestion but not quite what im after., one button is a submit button, the other is a link button that opens a modal. I want to have this modal hidden unless they uncheck the checkbox ( inside this modal the onsubmit button is seen again )

Comment: what you have tried so far??

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position:absolute` to make it above the another. Then based on the change event show and hide the button.

```js
function change(ele) {
  document.getElementById('btn2').style.display = ele.checked ? 'none' : 'inline'
}
```

```css
#div {
  position: relative
}
#btn2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check" onchange="change(this)" />

<div id="div">
  <button id="btn1">button1</button>
  <button id="btn2">button2</button>
</div>
```